# How to enter the user path and directly assign to the command prompt

Tags: excel, vba

Right now, I need to create a VBA macro wherein I need to open the cmd.exe then, it will ask the user to enter the path of the file they need to open. Then, the path should be put in the command line. As of now, I already open the location of the cmd.exe and added an inputbox function to enter the path. But, I don't know how to put the value of the path in my command line. Sorry if this seems trivial. I am new to VBA coding.

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
     Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "perl a.pl c:\temp", vbNormalFocus)
     Dim path As String
     path = InputBox("Enter a file path", "Title Here")
     Open path For Output As #1
     Close #1
End Sub
```

So, for example the user enter the path: C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Files\

In command prompt, it should look like this:

```
<C:\Windows\System32>**cd C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Files**
```

Is it possible to do that in VBA?
Thank you.

Comment: shell.Run ...................

Comment: I think you need extra quotes around the path to account for possible spaces, etc...  so something more like: `cd "C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Files"`